# Retrieve data from Firestore(wait query to finish)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

```
fun test(): MutableList<Usuari>  {
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val list: MutableList<Usuari> = mutableListOf()
    db.collection("users").document("m@gmail.com").get().addOnSuccessListener {
        result->
      val user=result.toObject(Usuari::class.java)
      list.add(user)

}
    return list
}
```

I have this code, I want to get a user from firestore, but there is a problem. All I do inside addOnSuccessListener is not saved(this function return a empty list). Then, I tried to make a Toast inside addOnSuccessListener and it show me that the user is added to list(BUT still return a empty list). It's really interesting. What can I do to keep this change after addonSuccessListener?

Comment: get() is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The listener is invoked some time later when the call completes.  Your function just returns what appears to be an empty list because the query isn't done.  You will not be able to return the result synchronous out of this function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there anyways that allow me to return the result  synchronous out of this function?

Comment: It wasn't an answer, just a comment. You can likely find an answer yourself with a Google search

Comment: I guess what I should do now is create a coroutine that wait get().addOnSuccessListener to be done and then returns the list ? Or should I wait only get() to be done and then add a listener and then returns the list?

Comment: You have a whole lot of options to choose from. I can't really tell you what's best for your case.

Comment: I didn't explain me well, I wanted to ask if listener is asynchronous as well or not.

Comment: That's what I was saying in my first comment. All Firebase APIs are asynchronous.

Comment: Now I understand perfectly, thanks!